# How can I determine the actual USB connection speed?

Tags: debian, usb

I did just connect a USB-mass storage to my Raspberry Pi with a cable that I do not really trust: I don't know whether it supports 5 Gbit/s (Superspeed).

Where can I find the actual speed of the link (480 Mbit/s or 5 Gbit/s)?

I know that the port supports 5 Gbit/s. I am only suspicious about the cable that has a violet color-code, which can be used for either "10 Gbit/s SuperSpeed" or "Huawei Super charge".

Benchmarking the drive did not give a clear result. And I don't want to buy a new cable just to check.

Comment: Try `lsusb -t`.